# border-radius not working in ie how can i implement so that it start working in ie

Tags: html, css

I am useing border-radius  css property   and its not working in ie  any one can suggest me any idea so that i will start working  in ie

```
<style>
   .myclass
   {
       border-radius:10px;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: mainly ie8  and  other too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 9 and 10 supports `border-radius` property.

For IE 8 and 7, you need to do some hacks using [**CSS3PIE**](http://css3pie.com/).

Just import the PIE.htc file and do the following,

```
border: 1px solid #696;
behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);
```

**NOTE:** please make sure url path is correct else you won't get it work.  Check my [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17018547/1671639).

Answer (score 3):

As you've not specified which version are you encountering this issue, if you are using IE < 9 than you need to use CSS3 Pie as @[Rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17873701/1542290) suggested, but if you are using IE > 9 than make  sure you use `<!DOCTYPE html>` and also use the below meta tag between the `<head>` tags

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Here, `edge` forces the IE to use the latest rendering engine.

Also make sure you have `Document Mode` set to `IE9 Standards` if it's IE9, same goes for ver 10

Answer (score 2):

Check [Progressive Internet Explorer](http://css3pie.com/). This makes IE to obey some CSS3 properties.

Comment: Wait until all the scripts get loaded completely. PIE will support border-radius property in IE from version 6. Read their Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

**PIE** makes `Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8` capable of rendering several of the most useful

```
 CSS3 decoration features.
```

**[Go to this site](http://css3pie.com/)**

Check to Compatible of **[Border Radius Browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)**

Comment: IE 9 Is capable to render `border-radius` without using pie

Comment: IE6  is no more.  **RIP IE6**

Comment: Read this Documentation http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/

Comment: Think about the degraded performance when using pie.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<style>
   .myclass
   {
  border-radius:10px;
 -ms-border-radius:10px;
   }
</style>
```

if this not work than you are using older browser u should use pie.htc for ie

Answer (score 1):

Use PIE this will support border radius in IE